# F# EventHandler Implementation

Tags: ios, .net, f#, xamarin.ios, slider

I have a `RangeSliderControl` from the following repository:

https://github.com/halkar/xamarin-range-slider

I am having trouble with implementing a method which will handle the slider being moved:

In Swift, we can simply do this:

```
priceSlider.addTarget(self, action: #selector(updatePrice),
                          for: .valueChanged)
```

and then we would have the `updatePrice` method:

```
func updatePrice() {
    //code
}
```

I don't understand how to do this in F#. I found the `addTarget` method, however, it has the following signature and I am not sure how to carry out the conversion. I assume the second argument would simply be `UIControlEvent.ValueChanged`, however what would the syntax for the `EventHandler` be?

[image]

EDIT:

[image]

Comment: If it's an f# question, why did you add the c# tag? Also, the swift tag is irrelevant

Comment: Well, EventHandlers are native to C#, aren't they?

Comment: They might be native to *.NET*. C# is a language, not a framework.

Comment: Could you please stop removing my tags?

Comment: Your question is not related to `ios` and it's not related to `.net`. Please don't add irrelevant tags. You are asking how something is done in `f#`, there's nothing in this question that makes it specific to `ios` nor to `.net`

Comment: It actually does, because AddTarget is a commonly used method in iOS, and people who develop for iOS are likely to know about it. So unless you are an iOS developer who's been developing for iOS in Xamarin and F# - in which cause you should know how to answer this question, please do not tell me what my own question is related to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the event handler would be registered as follows:

```
priceSlider.AddTarget(EventHandler (fun sender event -> updatePrice(...)), UIControlEvent.ValueChanged)
```

Comment: please check out the edit -  I corrected `.Value` to `.ValueChanged` but the issue still persists

Comment: I have updated the answer to correct the code based on your edit.

Answer (score 1):

The EventHandler should be something like:

```
fun evArgs -> .... your event handling code ....
```

and so the AddTarget call should be:

```
AddTarget (fun evArgs -> .... your event handling code ...), UIControlEvent.ValueChanged
```

source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/fsharp/language-reference/members/events

Comment: Would I simply add `evArgs` as the first argument to the addtarget method then?